# JavaScript history object causes Google Maps API V3 to fail on re-load

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

On our web app it shows a list of users images, you click on an image and it's shown with it's  geo-location data shown on a google map. This all works fine, but to keep the design clean and simple i have used a 'back' button. The button simply consists of using the JavaScript history object 'history.go(-1);'.

Once the user has been sent back to their list of images, all is still fine, they can use all the functionality of the app in this area. Also if they click on any other image than the one previously viewed all will be fine, the image viewer will initialize, and so will the google maps api.

The problem is when they click back off an image, then decide they didn't wish to actually go back, then re-visit the same image. This then stops all initialization of the google maps api.

It seems for some reason that the use of this method of going back causes the initialize(); function in the body="" to not work. However i'm lead to believe it's not the function but the body itself?

I have read through a lot of Google documentation on V3 of the maps API, but nothing much seems to exist around this issue. Maybe I'm the only one currently being dumb enough to come up against this problem.

Could anyone shed some light on the inner workings of the history object, and possibly point me in the direction of a solution.

Many thanks for all replies,

Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use the bfcache (back forward cache) events to call your initialize function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Working_with_BFCache